# How to pass parameter in cursor using explicit query

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, oracle12c

I am facing issues with below proc. I am new to PL/SQL and still exploring.

I need to pull all use detail on the basis on last_run from other table. Also, date is stored in varchar format hence need to parse that also.

```
procedure get_emp_info(rc_emp_info out ref_cursor) as
    last_sync varchar2;
begin
    select param_value into p_last_run from parameters where key = 'LAST_UPDATE_DATE';

    open rc_emp_info for
        select e.employee_id, e.user_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
        from   employee e
        where  last_run > p_last_run - 1;

end get_emp_info;
```

Kindly provide pointers to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Flagged as unclear. Please add some details to make this into a viable technical question or it will get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare p_last_run as a variable, then use it elsewhere.

```
declare
    p_last_run date;
begin
    SELECT to_date(param_value,'YYYYMMMDD' /*or whatever format is used*/) INTO p_last_run FROM parameters WHERE key = 'LAST_UPDATE_DATE'; 
    .
    .
    .
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Marko for quick suggestion. I am updating the proc and adding above mentioned functionality. Even after changes suggested by you still not working.